# Trying to construct regex with predefined, comma-separated list of words to capture

Tags: regex

I'm working on generating a Groovy script to parse a configuration string where I want to capture each of the words (for a combination of GitHub hooks and Jenkins scripts). I want to parse strings that look like this:

```
test:config1a,config1b/config2a/config3a,config3c
```

If I leave off the ability to have a comma separated list, I can get it working with a regex that looks like this:

```
configs = input_string =~ /^test:(config1a|config1b)\/(config2a|config2b)\/(config3a|config3b|config3c)/
```

However, adding the ability to use a comma separated string for any of the individual configs throws a wrench in it. I can get it to match, but I can't get out the list of values:

```
configs = input_string =~ /^test:((config1a|config1b),?)+\/((config2a|config2b),?)+\/((config3a|config3b|config3c),?)+/
```

The output of the above string would be:

```
[test:config1a,config1b/config2a/config3a,config3c, config1b, config1b, config2a, config3c, config3c]
```

The output is the same without Groovy if I put it in regex101.com (for some reason I can't save the regex to link here).

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex? What's the problem with `"test:config1a,config1b/config2a/config3a,config3c".split(":")[1].split("/").collect{it.split(",")}`, it seems to give you the "parsed" representation of the string directly, without any regex-fu?

Comment: I suppose that's true. I do have to have a regex to validate the string, but constructing that isn't as hard. I've figured out a way to get what I want, but the regex is getting ridiculous. Your idea is probably fine.

Comment: Why don't you just use `config(?:1[ab]|2[ab]|3[abc])` with the global flag?

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`config(?:1[ab]|2[ab]|3[abc])(?=[,/]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/na0SZa/2)

Details:

- `()` Capturing group
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `|` Or
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `?` Matches between zero and one times

**Groovy code**:

```
def input = "test:config1a,config1b/config2a/config3a,config3c"
def configs = (input =~ /config(?:1[ab]|2[ab]|3[abc])(?=[,\/]|$)/).collect { it }
```

Output:

```
[config1a, config1b, config2a, config3a, config3c]
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/JrXtEu)